# How do I get a watch function in a directive to fire when elements are shown or hidden in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to write an angularjs directive that works like foundation-equalize.  My problem is that I want it to work with elements that are hidden when the page loads and then appear when a user clicks something.  Various combination of watch and scope settings don't seem to work for me.

My directive

```js
myApp.directive("mmEqualize", [ function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        function equalize() {
            // my equalize function that only gets called on page load
        }
        // Even this most generic does not work
        scope.$watch(equalize());
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link : link
    };
} ]);
```

Master html template

```html
<div data-ng-show="someFlag">
    <div ng-include src="'included.html'"></div>    
</div>
    <button data-ng-click="someFlag = true">Show</button>
```

included.html

```html
<div class="row" data-mm-equalize="">
    <!-- divs to be equalized go here -->
</div>
```

The equalize function I have works so I haven't included it.  It gets called once, on page load, but I can't get it to be called when the show button is clicked.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `scope.$watch(equalize)` instead?

Comment: Yes!!!  Thanks so much.  Just need to a second pair of eyes I guess

Comment: Ok, was glad to help. Should I make this into an answer for you to accept?

Answer (score 1):

As described by raina77ow no functional parenthesis should be used in the call to $watch.

This code might clarify

```
var myFunc = function () {
  return "string";
};
console.log(myFunc); // Will log the functions code
console.log(myFunc()); // Will log the return from the function
```

In myFunc a function is stored if you use the identifier myFunc in code it will return that function. If you on the other hand add the () it will call the function and do what ever the function does.

Another way of calling the function is this

```
console.log(myFunc.call()); // Will log the return from the function, () == .call()
```

This is the syntax that $watch probably uses internally.